# Root partition filling up

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, disk-usage

Ubuntu just printed the message *"Partition "/" almost full. 600MB remaining"*
I am running Ubuntu 15.04
I have checked the root partition a few times since that occurred and it was filling up more and more... right now I have 0 bytes free space on it...
My root partition is 15GB in size, and before I created it I googled what a good size was (I'm new to linux) and I read 15GB was more than enough.
**apt-get clean** got me some free disk space, but that immediately piled up again :/
I read on another question that there was a bug with apt and that the solution was to manually update it, problem is I cannot download that updated version because /tmp is full...

I checked the disk with Baobab, and identified these as the biggest folders:

- usr 8.1GB

  - lib 5GB
  - share 2.2GB
- var 3GB

  - log 1.7GB (syslog file is 1.7GB, all other are a few kb)

I am pretty sure there is something wrong here (especially with that log folder), what can I do about it?
 Or should I just enlargen my root partition? and if yes, how do I do that?

Comment: It is something wrong. Something is filling your root. But is there a reason to have a separate /boot partition?

Comment: http://imgur.com/sIUDwSi  
Those are my partitions, I have /boot seperate from / and /home  
I have the root partition seperate because it only holds the system (right?) so that I could switch to another version of linux at any time without losing my files.

Comment: I just found that the syslog file is so big because all output from a console application I made in Kdevelop was saved in there, and I ran that quite a few times today, so that explains why the file 2GB in size...
still, I don't think it should do that, any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Root filling up although it should have some space](http://askubuntu.com/questions/97941/root-filling-up-although-it-should-have-some-space)

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason it was piling up:
I had developed a console application and because I am still used to windows started the binary via double click and expected it to open up in the terminal, instead it started writing 50Mb/s to the syslog file...