# installing Grub on btrfs : No space left on device

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, btrfs

I'm trying to repair grub after a Win10 install.
Here's the content of my disk:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc4476e04

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *       206848 566209347 566002500 269.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       566210560 567169023    958464   468M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda4       567171072 976773167 409602096 195.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       567173120 976773119 409600000 195.3G 83 Linux
```

sda2 contain wind10 and sda5 a btrfs volume (no encryption, no compression)

I had no luck with boot-repair, so I followed the instructions here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+bug/1721263

```
Boot with a Linux LiveCD
sudo mount -t btrfs -o subvol=@ /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Here I get the following eror:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: cannot open `/boot/grub/i386-pc/hello.mod': No space left on device.
```

sda5 has 56GB of free space. What is going on and how can I fix my system?
Thanks

Edit : more informations

```
df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5      204800000 149884472         0 100% /
udev            12307620         0  12307620   0% /dev

df -i
Filesystem      Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda5            0     0       0     - /
udev           3076905   777 3076128    1% /dev
```

Comment: Please edit your question to post the complete output of `df` and `df -i`

Comment: @user535733 I added these informations. I not sure how to interpret them. It's like the drive is read only.

Comment: Your Linux partition is *completely* full. So full it seemingly cannot even boot. So boot-repair won't work until you free some space. There are many [my-disk-is-100%-full](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97941/root-filling-up-although-it-should-have-some-space) questions.  Note that some of the questions involve a full "/boot partition" - those solutions WON'T work for you; different problem.

Comment: It's impossible, my partition was far from full, at least 50GB free. Ubuntu was fine until Windows 10 messed with the boot sequence.

Answer (score 0):

@user535733 was right, the BTRFS filesystem was full, more precisely out of metadata space.

[this was resolved here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994918/mounting-btrfs-no-space-available)

After that I could install grub without any error.