# Mounting BTRFS, no space available

Tags: filesystem, btrfs

After a win10 upgrade gone wrong, my boot sequence is broken and now I can't write on my BTRFS partition.

Here's the content of my ssd

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc4476e04

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *       206848 566209347 566002500 269.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       566210560 567169023    958464   468M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda4       567171072 976773167 409602096 195.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       567173120 976773119 409600000 195.3G 83 Linux
```

sda5 is my BTRFS partition, it contains

```
@  @apt-snapshot-release-upgrade-wily-2015-11-20_20:54:08  @home  boot
```

DF is telling there is no space left on device

```
df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5      204800000 149884472         0 100% /
udev            12307620         0  12307620   0% /dev

df -i
Filesystem      Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda5            0     0       0     - /
udev           3076905   777 3076128    1% /dev
```

However, 204800000 1K-blocks minus 149884472 used equal 54915528 KB free, Gparted and Palimpsest are also reporting more than 50GB free.

As [explained here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Problem_FAQ#I_get_.22No_space_left_on_device.22_errors.2C_but_df_says_I.27ve_got_lots_of_space), I tried to rebalance the FS

```
sudo btrfs fi show
Label: none  uuid: b6a97e55-1a85-4175-9fd8-3f3a623d527b
Total devices 1 FS bytes used 142.48GiB
devid    1 size 195.31GiB used 195.31GiB path /dev/sda5

sudo btrfs fi df /media/ubuntu/b6a97e55-1a85-4175-9fd8-3f3a623d527b/
Data, single: total=193.56GiB, used=141.15GiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=48.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=1.75GiB, used=1.29GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=39.28MiB

sudo btrfs fi balance start -dusage=5 /media/ubuntu /b6a97e55-1a85-4175-9fd8-3f3a623d527b/
ERROR: error during balancing '/media/ubuntu/b6a97e55-1a85-4175-9fd8-3f3a623d527b/': No space left on device
There may be more info in syslog - try dmesg | tail

dmesg | tail
[ 3059.160230] BTRFS info (device sda5): disk space caching is enabled
[ 3059.203601] BTRFS info (device sda5): detected SSD devices, enabling SSD mode
[ 3059.204291] BTRFS info (device sda5): checking UUID tree
[ 3059.206664] BTRFS warning (device sda5): btrfs_uuid_scan_kthread failed -28
[ 3201.876349] BTRFS info (device sda5): 4 enospc errors during balance
```

Ubuntu on this partition was totally fine before the windows upgrade.

What can I try to repair the BTRFS partition?

Thanks

Edit : Finally found the solution [here at the "Balance cannot run because the filesystem is full" paragraph](http://marc.merlins.org/perso/btrfs/post_2014-05-04_Fixing-Btrfs-Filesystem-Full-Problems.html)

Turns out the metadata was full and I had to add an empty device in order to rebalance the FS. No idea why this happened.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the solution [here at the "Balance cannot run because the filesystem is full" paragraph](http://marc.merlins.org/perso/btrfs/post_2014-05-04_Fixing-Btrfs-Filesystem-Full-Problems.html)

Turns out the metadata was full and I had to add an empty device in order to rebalance the FS. No idea why this happened.

Comment: I followed the mentioned blog post and added a 16GB flash drive to my root filesytem. I was able to run `btrfs balance`, however, I'm not able to remove the device due to `btrfs: unable to go below two devices on raid1` error. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/558363/65781